# Cache as false globally in $.get()

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

We are using `$.get()` in our codes to perform `AJAX` calls. We have noticed that `IE` actually caches our request and the DB hit doesn't happen until the browser cache is cleared.

To encounter this, we have used `cache:false` in few of the `$.get()` calls as given below:

```
$.get({url:'/Area/Controller/ActionMethod',cache:false, data:data})
       .then(function (response) {
           if (response != undefined) {
               alert('Success');
           }
       })
       .fail(function (xhr, statusText, error) {
           console.log(xhr);
       })
       .always(function () {
       });
```

But we have over 500 different `$.get()` calls in our code base. How can we globally set `cache` as `false` for all the `$.get()` calls.

I understand that if we were using `$.ajax()` calls, we would have been able to set `cache` as `false` in `$.ajaxSetup()`.

I searched for the above but couldn't find substantial results.

Please assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajaxSetup()` applies to all ajax calls even `$.get()`

Comment: I have $.get() scattered over the whole solution, not particular to a page or view. Where do u suggest I should keep $.ajaxSetup()?

Comment: don't you have a common file included in all the views?

Comment: I guess I can manage that, keep a script on the Layout page. Now cache:false will apply to $.post() as well, right? Any solution to only apply cache:false to $.get() calls especially?

Comment: Let me see..Thanks